# recreate eglCreateWindowSurface with same native window

Tags: x11, xserver, egl

I have written a library using EGL APIs. This library has 'init' and 'deinit' fuctions.
In 'init' function Native window id passed by user, using that native window id eglCreateWindowSurface  gets created. In 'deinit' function surface is destroyed using eglDestroySurface.

Now user call 'init' function again to create another eglCreateWindowSurface but he passed the same window id as earlier(as he has not closed his window), here eglCreateWindowSurface  failed with error EGL_BAD_ALLOC.

I read EGL specs

> If there is already an EGLSurface associated with win (as a result of
>   a previous eglCreateWindowSurface call), then an EGL_BAD_ALLOC error
>   is generated

I don't get this when i have already distroyed surface using eglDestroySurface why it is bothered to create again using same window id.

This problem can happen when xserver re-use earlier closed window id?

Answer (score 1):

Your `EGLSurface` may not be destroyed even after `eglDestroySurface` or `eglTerminate`. You probably called `eglMakeCurrent( display, surface... context)` - this binds your surface to the default framebuffer of the GL context. You need to unbind so that the surface can be truly deleted. Call `eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL_NO_SURFACE... EGL_NO_CONTEXT)` - this results in the the active thread releasing the context and the surface(s). Now you will find that EGL has forgotten/deleted the surface and you can reuse the Window ID. `eglReleaseThread` should do the same.

eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT); will unbind your surface and allow it to be deleted, it is not immediate, eglMakeCurrent will cause a glFlush on that context. So a  small bit of time might be needed to complete the draws you have called and resolve the image to the buffer. Otherwise the GPU can crash. Call glFinish() before eglMakeCurrent to ensure completion, or create fence and wait for it. It doesn't matter if you call eglDeleteSurface before or after eglMakeCurrent(... EGL_NO_SURFACE...), but all gl commands must happen before eglMakeCurrent(... EGL_NO_SURFACE..., EGL_NO_CONTEXT).  Because that makes no context current, and gl commands will not execute without a current context.

You can try calling eglGetCurrentContext and eglGetCurrentSurface to check if the surface still exists - you get a handle not EGL_NO_SURFACE. But the surface handle is definitely not useful after eglDeleteSurface. See EGL spec 1.5 section 3.7.4 - but as I said above, it exists only because its bound to the current context. See section 3.7.3

Comment: appreciate your effort to explain it...but i am sorry to say still it didn't work for me...i used eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL_NO_SURFACE... EGL_NO_CONTEXT) and post destroying surface, context eglGetCurrentSurface failed to get the surface and in next init call 'eglCreateWindowSurface' failed as asked in question.

Comment: Hmm, it does seem that there is some issue with reusing the xwindow ID. Can you check that its still a valid X object? There should be no more association in EGL after the steps I stated. So I have to think something with the Xwindow is not valid. If EGL is retaining something - then its a bug in that driver.

Comment: xwindow ID is a valid X object. There is just one change, xwindow is resized to new value. But that should not be the problem, if i don't close the existing EGL context and EGL Surface, same works perfect even with resized xwindow id. Only problem happens with close and reopen of egl window surface.

Answer (score 0):

Did `eglDestroySurface` return an EGL_TRUE value?

If not, the destruction may have failed.

Note that EGL_BAD_ALLOC may also be generated *if there are not enough resources to allocate the new surface.*

Comment: I am sorry not to mention `eglDestroySurface` return an EGL_TRUE value. Also it is not related to enough resources. If user close the window and pass new handle then egl surface gets created. It seems egl have made some entry of window ID which doesn;t get cleared even with success return of  `eglDestroySurface`. My concern is what if xserver return the same window ID which just closed then also egl will be failed to create egl Surface.  Also do i need to wait for some time before going to create egl surface with same window ID?